# Query post using shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this query for getting event custom posts

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type'=> 'events' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'events_photo', true); ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now I want to be create a shortcode for this query. I am using this code

```
function get_events(){
    global $post;
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type'=> 'events' );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post);
        $list_events= '';

        $event_title= get_the_title();
        $event_photo= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_photo', true); 

        $list_events.='
            <h2>'.$event_title.'</h2>
            <p>'.$event_photo.'</p>
        ';    
        $list_events= '';
    endforeach;
}

function insert_event($atts, $content=null){
$events_all= get_events();
return $events_all;
}
add_shortcode('all_events', 'insert_event');
```

but, it is not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: PLease, could you paste your result on insert_event function?

Comment: It is not showing anything. No log or error. I just need to be show custom post list with that shortcode. 

I need title & custom field will show in the post list.

Comment: well then the shorcode is not been called, try to check the trigger related with it

Comment: I don't know how. I am weak in PHP. Can you give me the code?

Comment: remove your `insert_event` function and call `get_events` in shortcode `add_shortcode('all_events', 'get_events');`

Comment: Have you found your solution?